# In JQuery, how do I access an array of DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, dom

In JQuery, how do I access an array of DOM elements?

am coding some inherited code that uses the jQuery MultiSelect widget.  I have a question that is a jQuery question (so no fair brushing this as a quesiton for the wedget maker).

The documentation and demos for this object is pretty good.  On this page, http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#selectedlist it has a bit of javascript code:

```
$("select").multiselect({
selectedText: function(numChecked, numTotal, checkedItems){
    return numChecked + ' of ' + numTotal + ' checked';
}
```

});

What I am interested in is "checkedItems".  The documentation says:

> The function receives three arguments: the number of checkboxes
>   checked, the  total number of checkboxes, and an array of the
>   checkboxes (DOM elements) that  were checked.

I want to modify this function so that I perform string operations on each member of this array, checkedItems.  How would I do this?

I hope I have provided enough information to determine an answer for a JQuery expert.  I think I have.

Answer (score 2):

Use `jQuery.each` to iterate over the array:

```
$.each(checkedItems, function (idx, ele){
    // ele is a reference to the individual element, so:
    console.log(ele.value); // outputs the value of the checkbox
});
```

**Documentation**

- `jQuery.each` - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/